# asp. net populate dropdownlist using javascript when a dropdownlist is change

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, dictionary, html-select

Hello I'm working with asp.net and javascript and i want to populate a dropdownlist2 with a List when dropdownlist1 is changed.

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Type");

    foreach (DataDefinitionResponse dr in _dr)
    {
        if (dr.Type != "Group" && dr.Type != "File")
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Name"] = dr.Name;
            row["Type"] = dr.Type;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            if (dr.Type == "Dropdown")
            {
                string[] strSplit = dr.ListValue.Split('|');
                List<string> lst = new List<string>();

                foreach (string word in strSplit)
                {
                    lst.Add(word);
                }
                dict.Add(dr.Name, lst);
            }
        }
    }
    ddlFieldName.DataSource = dt;
    ddlFieldName.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddlFieldName.DataValueField = "Type";
    ddlFieldName.DataBind();
    ddlFieldName.ClearSelection();
```

Above is my code to populate the first dropdownlist w/c is ddlFieldName. As you can see i use dictionary and declared global. Now I need to populated the 2nd dropdownlist using javascript.

Can anyone help me with this.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

When Dropdownlist1 is changed get that element which is selected by using following script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$jq14(document).ready(function () {
$jq14("#Dropdownlist1").change(function (e) {
window.location = "@Url.Content("~/Controller/ActionMethod/?id=")" + $jq14(this).val();
});
});
</script>
```

Then in your controller action method receive that value and put it into ViewBag object like 
ViewBag = id;
Then finally in your view get that ViewBag value in your Dropdownlist2 to as seeder for loop or list population

Comment: If you are using ASP.Net MVC then this works. Actually you have to get the value selected from dropdownlist1 when a change event is occurred, Once you get that value for example dropdownlist1 contains Countries when a country is selected from dropdownlist1 you have to show states in that country so you call your controller method and pass the value (the selected country). At your controller you get that country and find its states list and return it to your view. In your view you populate your 2nd dropdown list with the data returned from controller.